# Union leads to error converting varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm reposting my question from yesterday with the addition of code.
I'm creating a new table LAB_RESULT as a union of two tables (Labs and CTE). A column called `result_num` (`numeric (18,5)`) is causing problems in `LAB_RESULT`.

Table LAB_RESULT is declared first with explicit data types.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LAB_RESULT
(
    [LAB_RESULT_CM_ID] VARCHAR (36),
    [RESULT_NUM] NUMERIC (18,5)
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[LAB_RESULT] (LAB_RESULT_CM_ID, RESULT_NUM)
   SELECT LAB_RESULT_CM_ID, RESULT_NUM
   FROM [etl].[lab_result]
```

`LAB_RESULT` draws from `varchar` columns in tables `LABS` and `CTE`. I have used `try_cast` in both A and B to make sure nothing slips through.

So when I select from (LABS U CTE), I get:

> Msg 8114
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric

but when I select from only `LABS` or only `CTE` (all there just commented out) the data loads fine.

This is happening even if I use `cast(null as numeric)`.

```
SELECT LAB_RESULT_CM_ID, RESULT_NUM
FROM
    ((SELECT 
          NEWID() AS LAB_RESULT_CM_ID,
          CAST(NULL AS NUMERIC(18, 5)) AS RESULT_NUM
      FROM [dbo].[Labs] as labs

      UNION
      (SELECT
           NEWID() as LAB_RESULT_CM_ID,
           CAST(NULL as NUMERIC(18, 5)) AS RESULT_NUM
       FROM CTE)
```

What gives? I would really appreciate some insight. TIA!

Comment: You might have a trigger on the table or other columns that are causing the problem.

Comment: Secondly, without underlying data this can not be tested as the header suggest. And as per the header, the solution is simple if it is not causing the trigger.